# Colourful commenting in RStudio using #' * *

Tags: r, colors, rstudio, comments

Since when can you do color comments in R?

```
#'*this some colorful comment*
```

#'**

-> gives you the ability to annotate in colour .

I found this by sheer accident & couldn't find anything on the internet about this matter ;

Is this meant for something else, or was it just a secret?

Comment: `#'`signals the start of a roxygen comment, see e.g. http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/man.html#roxygen-comments which are used for documenting functions inside packages. The change in color by using * ... * is markdown code and means emphasize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thx to Stefan, i now know its Roxygen!